# Javascript regexp for smile icon replacements

Tags: javascript, regex

Could someone help with regexp for replacement of :) for `<img src="etc"/>`?

in all these cases it shouldn't be replaced:

- :Dtest test :Dtest - from begining of word or start
- test:Dtest - between text

in all other cases it should be replaced by `<img src="etc"/>`

Can't figure out proper pattern.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
string.replace(/:D(?=\s|$)/g, '<img src="etc"/>')
```

I tried it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rmQSx/2/) and it seems to work, if I understand your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

```
"bla :D bla:D".replace(/([^\w]|^)(:D)([^\w]|$)/g, '$1<img src="jeej.png"/>$3')
```

Comment: This will remove the whitespace as well.

Comment: doesn't replace smile at the end ;)

Comment: It does replace the smiley at the end.

Comment: i have copied your example in firebug and launched, the result it returns is "bla <img src="jeej.png"/> bla:D"

Answer (score 0):

Your example (looking for just the ":D" smiley) could be solved with this:

```
var newStr = oldStr.replace(/([\W\b^]):-?D\b/g, '$1<img src="etc"/>');
```

Don't forget that you'll need other patterns if you want to cover things like 8) :( :P :), etc.

If you do something like

```
/([\W\b^])([\:8B])-?([DP\(\)\*])(?=[\W\b$])/g
```

or whatever other permutations of smilies you want to allow, you'll have the eyes and mouth captured in match groups 2 and 3, so you can decide which image to substitute. Or you could use string manipulation for this instead, which is probably what I'd do.

Comment: test :D test:D:D in this string, first :D is not replaced ;)

Comment: @Beck: You're right--":" doesn't create a word boundary with other non-word characters. I'll edit.

Comment: doesn't \b in front and \b in end means it will only affect if :D is located at the end of word or at it's end? But what if test*whitespace*:D*whitespace*test:D:D ?

Comment: invalid quantifier ?<[\W\b])([:8B])-?([DP()*])(?=[\W\b]) returned by firebug

Comment: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript i have found this, maybe this will help? :)

Comment: @Beck I was actually about to post *that exact link*. Anyway, I've removed the lookbehind around the first `[\W\b]`; you can use the method in the article if it helps. The "invalid quantifier" error was most likely caused by the `*`, which I believe should be allowed within a character class, but I've escaped it in the above edit and it appears to work now. It would be better with a lookbehind, but I forgot about JS not allowing those. Hope this helps.

Comment: I can use actionscript if there is better support for regex. Is there? Just a sec, let me test this one. Btw here is testboard i'm using all the time http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/ you can play around there :) , just choose javascript at top

Comment: @Beck: That I couldn't tell you, since I haven't used ActionScript. XRegExp, however, is an alternative JS regex library that I've heard good things about. http://xregexp.com/ I'd go with that if I were you; using backreferences is really the right way to do this, and I don't think this can really be done comprehensively without them. Thanks for the testboard link, I'll be using that. :)

Comment: @Beck: BTW, one of the consequences of the lack of backreferences is that in your "test :D test:D:D" example, only the first :D in ":D:D" will be matched. In fact, the more I think about this, the more I think you'll have better results with non-regex string manipulation.

Comment: It's hell of a headache this regex :D

Comment: @Beck Yeah, I'm afraid so. This is one of those things that turns out to be WAY more complicated than it seems at first. And it's growing: I just edited to allow for ^ and $, because those won't create a word boundary with non-word characters either. Regex seems usable, especially with backreferences, but string manipulation is looking better all the time.

Comment: Until it's not eating too much time. ;) I'll try to look into actionscript regex tomorrow and simple string manipulations.

Answer (score -1):

I'd go with

`"text :D text :D.".replace(/\b:D\b/g, '<img src="etc" />');`